# How to place files containing increasing numeric names consecutively in the terminal

Tags: bash, file, terminal, command-line, xmgrace

I have certain files named something like *file_1.txt, file_2.txt, ..., file_40.txt* and I want to plot them in the terminal using xmgrace like this:

```
xmgrace file_01.txt file_02.txt [...] file_40.txt
```

What would be a bash code, maybe a `for loop` code so that I don't have to write them one by one from 1 to 40, please?

[Edit:]
I should mention that I tried to use the `for loop` as follows: `for i in {00-40}; do xmgrace file_$i.txt; done`, but it didn't help as it opens each file separately.

Comment: `xmgrace file_{1..40}.txt` see: [BraceExpansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

Comment: please update the question with the `for loop` code you attempted along with an explanation of what you mean by *`it didn't help me`*

Comment: We encourage questioners to **show** what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of the tool you use:

```
xmlgrace file_*.txt
```

using a [*glob*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) (this will treat *all* files matching the pattern)

or as [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel) wrote in comments:

```
xmlgrace file_{1..40}.txt
```

This is [*brace expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

For general purpose, if the tool require a loop:

```
for i in {1..40}; do something "$i"; done
```

or

```
for ((i=0; i<=40; i++)); do something "$i"; done
```

Comment: `xmlgrace file_*.txt` will also expand to `file_41.txt` (when it exists) and shows `file_10.txt` before `file_2.txt`. You might want `xmlgrace file_[1-9].txt file_[1-3][0-9].txt file_40.txt`. The brace expansion is fine.